# On the predictive distribution regarding Bayesian methods for pattern recognition

Tags: probability, bayesian

I am following *Pattern recognition and machine learning* by Byshop and I was trying to derive myself the predictive distribution resulting from a new data point. For the sake of clarity I post the piece of text in question: [image]

where $w$ are the parameters  of the model treated as a random variable since we are in the Bayesian setting.

Anyhow I was trying to derive this myself and what I would do is

$$p(t|x, \textbf{x}, \textbf{t}) = \int p(t|x, \textbf{x}, \textbf{t},w) dw = \int \frac{p(t,x, \textbf{x}, \textbf{t},w)}{p(x, \textbf{x}, \textbf{t},w)} dw = \dots$$

And then I am unsure how to proceed. How could this be done?

EDIT: I was trying to apply Bayes rule with multiple conditions as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408774/bayes-rule-with-multiple-conditions) but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your first step. You need to marginalize out the "w" term, so you should be integrating the joint distribution of t and w over all w. It should be:

$p(t|x, \textbf{x}, \textbf{t}) = \int p(t, w|x, \textbf{x}, \textbf{t}) dw$

Then, you can use the conditional probability rule,

$\int p(t, w|x, \textbf{x}, \textbf{t}) dw = \int p(t|w, x, \textbf{x}, \textbf{t})p(w|x,\textbf{x},\textbf{t})dw$

Now, recognizing that $t$ does not depend on $\textbf{x}$ and $\textbf{t}$, and $w$ does not depend on $x$,

$\int p(t|w, x, \textbf{x}, \textbf{t})p(w|x,\textbf{x},\textbf{t})dw = \int p(t|w,x)p(w| \textbf{x}, \textbf{t})dw$